# Receive sms broadcast on KitKat

Tags: android, smsmanager

I really tried it all, the broadcast receiver doesn't receive new incoming sms broadcasts.
I'm running on my phone 4.4.4, I just want to listen to incoming messages, that is.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

the broadcast receiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public SmsReceiver() {}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("v", "SMS onReceive");
}
```

gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dev.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<action>` you've defined in the `<receiver>`'s `<intent-filter>` in the manifest is incorrect. It should be:

```
 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

You might be confusing it with the class constant String identifier `android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`, which has the value shown above.

Comment: thanks! I got confused because of this blog:http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html